# Java Class/Package interaction

Tags: java

I have two .java files that I trying to compile with `javac` in OS X terminal.

DieRun.java

```
package die;

public class DieRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Die d6 = new Die(6);

    }
}
```

And Die.java:

```
package die;

import java.util.Random;

public class Die {

    private int sides;
    private int value;
    private Random rng;

    public Die(int sides) {
        this.sides = sides;
        this.rng = new Random();
        this.value = this.roll();
    }

    public Die(int sides, int seed) {
        this.sides = sides;
        this.rng = new Random(seed);
        this.value = this.roll();
    }

    public int roll() {
        this.value = this.rng.nextInt(this.sides) + 1;
        return this.value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

Using `javac *.java` they both compile without any errors but when I try to run one of them (eg. `java DieRun` ) it fails with error: Could not find or load main class DieRun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classes are in a package named "die". To run them, you have a few options.

The quick option is to remove the `package` declaration so they are in the default package. Not the greatest practice in general but perfectly valid for quick one-off applications.

The correct option is:

1. Put your source files in a subdirectory named "die".
2. Compile them there (so that the class files are in "die" - this is the actual important part).
3. Move up to the parent directory and run `java die.DieRun`.

Directory structure must match package structure. There is slightly more to it, regarding current class path, etc., but this will get you on your feet.

You may wish to read the [official tutorial on packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/) as well.

Comment: Already had directory called die so I navigated up a directory and ran `java die.RunDie` which worked.
Java is my first 'compilable' language so the whole package and run concept is pretty strange to me. So thank you.

Comment: @robjtede Glad you got it working. Note that this type of packaging isn't a general feature of compiled languages, it's an interesting feature of Java. C++, for example, does not require directory structure to match namespace hierarchies. Java's class and package layouts are very closely tied to file names and directory structure.